# How to $pull ObjectId from multiple collections simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For a dating site I have a db of hundreds of different Users.

Fields such as "matches", "heartedMe" contain the ObjectId of different users in Array form.

When I delete a user I need to search every collection and delete any references to the deleted user by $pull ing their ObjectId from all relevant fields.

Any thoughts on the sort of query I would need to run? Currently I've just found All Users!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you post your schema/s?

Comment: write a comman function for pull the userid from collection. Take the collections you want to remove user put in array. using forEach send the item to comman function